# Pass NSDictionary from Javascript to Objective-c in JavascriptCore

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, javascriptcore

I'm using `JavascriptCore` in my app. Now, I'm passing some variables to the `JSContext` that can then be passed back to Objective-C. However, one of the variables, an NSDictionary, is not passing through correctly. I run the code below:

```
var evaluate = function(variables) {
    app.setDictionary(variables.dictionary);
}
```

This is a simple example that has these following methods set up in `JSContext`.

This is the `setDictionary()` method:

```
- (void)setDicationary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    self.mutableDictionary = [dictionary mutableCopy];
}
```

This is `variables.dictionary`:

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    return self.values;
}
```

And this is how I call `evaluate()`:

```
JSValue *jsFunction = self.context[@"evaluate"];
JSValue *value = [jsFunction callWithArguments:@[self.variables]];
```

However, in the setDictionary method, I don't get an NSDictionary, but instead get a NSString containing `[object Object]`.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Please, add Objective-C code counterpart to the question.

Comment: @BorisVerebsky I added it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although JavaScriptCore automatically converts types between Objective-C or Swift and JavaScript, I suggest to implement explicit conversion. Automatic conversion doesn't always work as developer may expect. For example `undefined` is converted to `@"undefined"` in case, when `NSString` is used.

Try something like:

```
- (void)setDicationary:(JSValue *)jsDictionary {
    if ([jsDictionary isUndefined] || [jsDictionary isNull]) {
        jsDictionary = nil;
    }
    self.mutableDictionary = [jsDictionary toDictionary];
}
```

Note that JavaScript uses object as dictionary, so you should be very careful with argument that you passing to Objective-C code. Passing any system object will result to recursive conversion of that object to `NSDictionary`.